# open and read a csv file from storage path and convert it into mysql table in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, import, upload

```
if (($file = Storage :: get('/logos/ ' . $filename )) !== FALSE) {
     while ( ($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !==FALSE )
     {
        $csv_data = new Issue();
        $csv_data->id = $data [0];
        $csv_data->firstname = $data [1];
        $csv_data->lastname = $data [2];
        $csv_data->email = $data [3];
        $csv_data->gender = $data [4];
        $csv_data->save ();
    }
    fclose($file);   
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given"

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** after @Naeem comment (Thank you).

`$file` is the content, not the file pointer. You could use [`str_getcsv()`](https://php.net/str_getcsv) to parse the CSV lines:

```
$data = Storage::get('/logos/' . $filename);
$csv = array_map(function($row) {
    $data = str_getcsv($row) ;
    $csv_data = new Issue();
    $csv_data->id = $data [0];
    $csv_data->firstname = $data [1];
    $csv_data->lastname = $data [2];
    $csv_data->email = $data [3];
    $csv_data->gender = $data [4];
    $csv_data->save ();
}, explode("\n", $data));
```

Maybe `\n` should be updated using `\r\n` of (`PHP_EOL`) depending of the newline of the CSV.

If you only want the first line (usually header), you could use :

```
$data = Storage::get('/logos/ ' . $filename);
$lines = explode("\n", $data, 2) ; // create an array of 2 entry (first line, and the rest).
$first_line = reset($lines);

$data = str_getcsv($first_line) ;
$csv_data = new Issue();
$csv_data->id = $data [0];
$csv_data->firstname = $data [1];
$csv_data->lastname = $data [2];
$csv_data->email = $data [3];
$csv_data->gender = $data [4];
$csv_data->save();
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work. you are already reading the file on Storage::get which is returning $content not $file

Comment: Thank you @Naeem for your feedback. I've updated the answer. Could you please tell me if it works now? If not, I'll delete this answer. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the update. what if i only want to read the first line means only header line not the whole file?

Comment: @Naeem I've updated the answer to get only the header line.

Comment: $first_line : and then again explode it with "," ?